# How pass a interface's property as parameter in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Sorry if this question is too stupid :D
I have an `interface`:

```
interface APIRoutes {
  SIGNUP  : string,
  LOGIN   : string,
}
```

And a `const`, like `routes config`.

```
const APIs: APIRoutes = {
  SIGNUP  : Config.baseURL + "/signup",
  LOGIN   : Config.baseURL + "/login",
}
```

I want to declare a `function`, it will take one of those route as `parameter`:

```
const callAPI = async (APIRoute: string, body: any, headers: any) => {
    //...
}
```

The problem is, I don't know how to make this function only accept one of the `APIRoutes` properties.
I mean something like this:

```
callAPI(APIs.SIGNUP, ...)                 // => OK
callAPI(APIs.STACKOVERFLOWISAWESOME, ...) // => ERROR
```

How can I do this?
Not only interface, whatever can solve this problem is great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) operator. It takes an object type and produces a union of its keys.

```
interface APIRoutes {
  SIGNUP  : string,
  LOGIN   : string,
}

const APIs: APIRoutes = {
  SIGNUP  : "/signup",
  LOGIN   : "/login",
}

const callAPI = async (APIRoute: keyof APIRoutes) => {
    
}

console.log(callAPI('asdasd'));
console.log(callAPI('SIGNUP'));
console.log(callAPI('LOGIN'));
```

[Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIAUCSAlA9gV0gGdkBvAWAChlkBlTAcQDkBVdGgLmSLClAHMANFRoAZAPINMTGsi48+IIVQC+VKglwgeaLES4YcBYsgC8ZEXUat2c5ACIA9EWD8Q+AA73h1ZBKkynA6OADa4-KDequqUmtpgyAhwISGGZshwRACeIAjIABSGeIQQXADWEFm4MLpGJUQAlGYAfBa+NNGUGlpEuCEQAHRh-PlJKYb5AOSZACazkw0NANzd2n2Dw6PJqVhT9MxsC8urvf1D4Vvju5P+0kcrlEA)